# MongoDB Aggregation on nested levels

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I use MongoDB 4.4.

I'm trying to make a Mongo aggregation query that would return me a document with nested arrays. To specify the context:
I have offers, which contain modules, which contain items, which themselves contain notes. I have a collection for each entity:

```
offers: {
    _id: '64a6c6ed3f24ff001b74cf9d',
    name: 'offer name',
}

modules: {
    _id: '64a6c6ed3f24ff001b74cfab',
    name: 'module name',
    offerId: '64a6c6ed3f24ff001b74cf9d',
}

items: {
    _id: '5e984aea5e6df000399e6b97',
    name: 'module name',
    moduleId: '64a6c6ed3f24ff001b74cfab',
}

notes: {
    _id: '64c78caf0e5791001b15833c',
    name: 'note name',
    itemId: '5e984aea5e6df000399e6b97',
}
```

With my query, I want to retrieve an offer by `_id`, and this query returns the offer with its modules, the items for each module, and the notes for each item. Basically an object like this:

```
offer: {
  _id: "64a6c6ed3f24ff001b74cf9d",
  name: "offer name",
  modules: [
    {
      _id: "64a6c6ed3f24ff001b74cfab",
      name: "module name",
      items: [
        {
          _id: "5e984aea5e6df000399e6b97",
          name: "item name",
          notes: [
            {
              _id: "64c78caf0e5791001b15833c",
              name: "note name"
            },
            {
              // other note
            },
            ...
          ]
        },
        {
          // other item
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    {
      // other module
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I wrote this query:

```
db.getCollection("offers").aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
        _id: ObjectId('64a6c6ed3f24ff001b74cf9d'),
    }
  },
  {
      $lookup: {
          from: 'modules',
          localField: '_id',
          foreignField: 'offerId',
          as: 'modules',
      },
  },
  {
      $unwind: '$modules',
  },
  {
      $lookup: {
          from: 'items',
          localField: 'modules._id',
          foreignField: 'moduleId',
          as: 'items',
      },
  },
  {
      $unwind: '$items',
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'notes',
        localField: 'items._id',
        foreignField: 'itemId',
        as: 'notes',
    },
  },
  {
      $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        name: { $first: "$name" },
        modules: { 
            $push: {
                _id: "$modules._id",
                name: "$modules.name",
                items: {
                    $push: {
                        _id: "$items._id",
                        name: "$items.name",
                        notes: {
                          $push: {
                              _id: "$notes._id",
                              name: "$notes.name",
                          }
                        },
                    }
                },
            }
        }
      }
  },
  {
      $project: {
        _id: 1,
        name: 1,
        modules: 1,
      }
  },
  
]);
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

> Unrecognized expression '$push'

Is it impossible to do nested `$push`(es)? In this case how to achieve the desired result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add some representative examples of your collections documents?

Comment: I have corrected query and added collections details, thanks.

Comment: Instead of unwinding and then later regrouping, would nested lookups work?

Comment: How could I do that? Any example?

Answer (score 1):

The `$push` aggregation operator is not valid in a nested value.  To get your desired result, use a separate $group for each level, like:

```
{$group:{
  _id:{
       _id:"$_id", 
       module:{_id:"$modules._id", name:"$modules.name"},
       item:{_id:"$garantyItems._id", name:"$garantyItems.name"}
  },
  notes:{$push:{ _id:"$notes._id", name:"$notes.name"}}
}},
{$group:{
  _id:{
        _id:"$_id._id",
        module:"$_id.module",
  },
  items:{$push:{_id:"$_id.item._id",name:"$_id:item.name",notes:"$notes"}}
}},
{$group:{
  _id:"$_id._id",
  modules:{$push:{_id:"$_id.module._id",name:"$_id.module.name",items:"$items"}}
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per @user20042973 mentioned in the comment, nested `$lookup` stages should be easier in joining multiple collections in the nested arrays and customizing its projection.

```
db.offers.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: ObjectId("64a6c6ed3f24ff001b74cf9d")
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "modules",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "offerId",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "items",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "moduleId",
            pipeline: [
              {
                $lookup: {
                  from: "notes",
                  localField: "_id",
                  foreignField: "itemId",
                  pipeline: [
                    {
                      $unset: "itemId"
                    }
                  ],
                  as: "notes"
                }
              },
              {
                $unset: "moduleId"
              }
            ],
            as: "items"
          }
        },
        {
          $unset: "offerId"
        }
      ],
      as: "modules"
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_jxIPRW1Pa_)

Comment: Thanks for reply, it works well with Mongo 6 but with my Mongo version (4.4) I have an error: $lookup with 'pipeline' may not specify 'localField' or 'foreignField'

Comment: Hi @skumy, ya, in this case you should modify the query as [this demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UFLEznFmH3_).